# I can't make the infoWindow work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I am new to JavaScript
I have read the question: [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example) and tried the answer supplied by Daniel Vassallo

```
var Australia = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.16881, 132.72259);

var placesIhaveBeen = [
    ['Aalborg Airport Flight leaves at:xxxxxx', 57.04807, 9.91857]
    ['Copenhagen Airport Arrives leaves at:xxxxxx', 55.61541, 12.64885]
    ['Dubai Airport Flight Arrives at: xxxxx', 25.25278, 55.36444]
    ['Sydney Airport Flight Arrives at:xxxxxx', -33.93947, 151.17522]];

var markers = [];
var iterator = 0;
var map;
var infowindows = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;

function initialize()
{
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: Australia,
        mapTypeControl: false

    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap-Canvas"),
        mapOptions);

    //flight path Polyline
    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(57.04807, 9.91857),
    new google.maps.LatLng(55.61541, 12.64885),
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.25278, 55.36444),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.93947, 151.17522)
    ];
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
    //end of flight path polyline

    for (i = 0; i < placesIhaveBeen.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(placesIhaveBeen[i][1], placesIhaveBeen[i][2], placesIhaveBeen[i][3], placesIhaveBeen[i][4]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.eve.addDomListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(placesIhaveBeen[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

That is my entire Script :S

I know I have some flightpath in the middle of it, I want that to show as well - as the markers (placesIhaveBeen).

So the deal is I want the marker with infowindows and the polyline to show at the same time, but I can't make it work - please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors:

There are missing comma in array definition of `placesIhaveBeen`:

```
var placesIhaveBeen = [
    ['Aalborg Airport Flight leaves at:xxxxxx', 57.04807, 9.91857],
    ['Copenhagen Airport Arrives leaves at:xxxxxx', 55.61541, 12.64885],
    ['Dubai Airport Flight Arrives at: xxxxx', 25.25278, 55.36444],
    ['Sydney Airport Flight Arrives at:xxxxxx', -33.93947, 151.17522]
];
```

`infowindow` is not defined so the line

```
var infowindows = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

should be

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

And there is a typo in `google.maps.eve.addDomListener`. It should be `google.maps.event.addDomListener`.

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/napun/1/edit). Map containter is named differently.

Comment: Thank you! that made it work - perhaps I should be working so many hours on the same that late on the day(Danish local time)

Comment: Along with all this, you should start getting used to Developer Tools (Console) within your Browser. Chrome `Ctrl + Shift + J`, Firefox `Ctrl + Shift + K`, IE `F12`